# Finding highest point of vector with DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector, dem

What I have is:

- ArcGIS 10.4.
- DEM raster file.
- Feature class "street".

What I need is the highest point of the street.

Comment: Run (watershed processing tool of choice, e.g. ArcHydro Tools) to get catchments which will be situated on the ridges in your DEM. Should get you pretty close to what you need with an out of the box-toolbox.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I would have to install the ArcHydroTools first, I tried one of the other approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My Approach would be to ...
1. Convert the street vertices to points with the "Feature Vertices to Points Tool".

[image: Feature Vertices to Points Tool]

2. Use the Spatial Analyst tool "Extract Values to Points" to get points with road data and elevation values.

[image: Extract Values to Points Tool]

3. Use the Summarize tool to get the Maximum Value for each street.

[image]

Comment: do you think extracting only vertices (start, end, mid, all or some) would gurantee getting the desired maximum height from a raster?

Comment: That's a fair objection to the method I've described. It depends on the density of vertices in the road layer when compared to the DEM.

Comment: As it refers to a forest area with a very low road density, it worked perfectly fine for me! thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [zonal statistics as table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) tool from spatial analyst to get desired outcome. As the link explains, if you have vector features as zones, an internal vector to raster conversion is run before calculation. If you select your ObjectIDs as the zone field and pick the Max operator, you should be able to get the highest DEM value overlaid. One warning though, it will do the calculation based on your geometry, for example if you have multipart lines, it will give you the result based on all accompanying features.

Comment: I will try this too in a free minute. Seems to be pretty straight approach.

Comment: @Kevin, please do and let us know. I cannot know for sure the context of your  query and [error margins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) of it as a result.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert your lines to points with "Feature Vertices To Points" (Advanced License needed). If you have Spatial-Analyst extension you can then use "Extract Values to Points" to bring the raster values to your points.